# wp_register_script going crazy

Tags: wordpress, enqueue

So, I am working on a custom post type and have a css and a js file related to it. I had them enqueuing just fine until it didn't anymore.

Here is the code I have:

```
function enqueue_avada_child()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('avada-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('child-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');

    wp_enqueue_style('rentals-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/rentals/css/rentals.css');

    wp_enqueue_script('rentals-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/rentals/js/rentals.js', array(), 1.0, true);

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_avada_child');
```

The css file loads fine, the js stopped loading on my custom post type page. It does load tho on other pages. Why?

Comment: Do you have a custom template for that post type?

Comment: Yes, I do. I will migrate the website live so it helps people to see it.